# Specifying Relationships in Models in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm an ASP.NET MVC4 beginner and I'm trying to create a blog kind of. I have a problem with creating relationships in my models. Background of my issue is that, I have a model (Users.cs) with user information, a model (Posts.cs) containing posts information, and a third model (Comments.cs) containing comments information.

So a user can have many posts but a post can belong to only one user,
a user can have many comments but a comment can belong to only a user,
a post can have many comments but a comment can only belong to a post,

My question is, how do I write the three models? So far I have this:

```
public class Users
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }    
    public string Lastname  { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegDate { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Posts> Post { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Comments> Comment { get; set; }
}

class Posts
{
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public string PostTitle { get; set; }
    public string PostContent { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public int CommentID { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Comments> Comment { get; set; }
    public virtual Users user { get; set; }
}

public class Comments
{
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }
    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public int PostID { get; set; }

    public virtual Posts post { get; set; }
    public virtual Users user { get; set; }  
}
```

Please how do I write the three models correctly? Help!!!

Comment: I'm guessing this is Entity Framework? What isn't working/what error(s) do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You have strongly typed model classes, and you're already using them correctly. You just need to remove the redundant properties pointing to ID's - `Comments` doesn't need an `int AuthorID` pointing to the author when it already has `Users user`.

Remove these properties:

```
class Posts
{
    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
}

public class Comments
{
    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public int PostID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks wiseguy. would try it again and let you know the progress.

Comment: Forgot to thank Aaroninus for answering my question. Sorry. Grateful.